# Two-tap voltage divider, why can't I solve for the center resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-divider

### Background

I'm working on a circuit involving an AC-excited sensor bridge, and am trying to figure out ways to detect a short between the two bridge legs, as that causes the bridge to fail to the "wrong side" (i.e. indicate all is well, when the sensor says all is *not* well).  One idea I had for this was to bias the in-amp that measures the bridge into its operating range from the *input* side, so that shorted inputs would cause the output common-mode voltage to shift dramatically, rendering the failure detectable by downstream circuitry.

### The problem

So, I set to design a simple bias network to do this task:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6lhPv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From this design, I went to solve the circuit for R by treating it as two voltage dividers with equations as follows:

$$V_1=5\frac{R+1M\Omega}{R+2.23M\Omega}$$
$$V_2=5\frac{1M\Omega}{R+2.23M\Omega}$$

However, when I plugged in a V1 of 2.2625V and a V2 of 2.2375V (2.25V +/- 12.5mV) and went to find my unknown R by treating the equations as a system, I was unable to come up with a solution, either by hand calculation or using Wolfram Alpha.  Initially, this was because I had R1 set to 1MOhm, which was correct for an original center voltage of 2.5V, but wrong for the current center voltage of 2.25V.  So, I solved a simple voltage divider for that center voltage and transposed the R1 I found (1.23MOhm, in E192) into my working circuit, but that didn't work either -- I'm getting far closer now, but it seems like I may have run out of resistor precision before I can get the small differential voltage drop I want?

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 equations and 1 unknown variable R. Your system of equations is overdetermined. Just use the second equation, solving it is easier than solving the first one.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system

For the record, it is sometimes useful to have an overdetermined system. One can use least-squares method, averaging, median to "improve" the measurement.

Edit : The original data does not make sense, V1 should be greater than 2.5V since R1 = R3 = 1Mohms and R2 should be greater than 0...

Comment: I tried solving the second equation, got an answer, but if I try plugging it into the first equation I get a voltage that's way off the mark I need it to be at...

Comment: Perhaps you made a mistake in V1 or V2. Are you sure you have the right values?

Comment: I am sure I have the right values

Comment: R2 is greater than 0, right? R1 = R3 right?

Then the minimum value for V1 is 2.5V, it cannot be lower than 2.5V

Comment: You made a mistake, V1 = 2.7625V

Comment: That's the issue *laughs*

Comment: If V1 = 2.2625V and Vcc = 5V, then it means that R2 is negative. You did something wrong...

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong -- I forgot to change R1/R3 to match having to move my center point (it originally was set to be centered on 2.5V)